# How to determine sample weights, when the prevalence in the population is based on percentages

Tags: r, resampling, weighted-regression, stratification, survey-weights

The central question is: How to do I determine the weights, when prevalence in the population is expressed as percentages?

I have posted [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458098/correcting-dfs-when-using-sample-weights-with-lm) on Stack Overflow: According to the solution proposed by IRTFM, (also see the old answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268689/weighted-regression-in-r)), the absolute value of the weights used in OLS matters. I have provided some quick "proof" that weights matter at the bottom of the page.

If the absolute value of the weights matters, then how do you determine what those values are, when prevalence in the population is expressed as percentages?

Let's assume that I have a fixed sample, and I attribute this sample, percentages based on the population:

I have a data set, `Population_percentages`, with the population percentages for each municipality as follows (example `dput` listed at the end of the question):

```
# A tibble: 128 x 8
   Province Municipality  year   Sex Age   Party Educ  Percentage
   <chr>    <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
 1 A        X             2000     0 young left  high    0.00363 
 2 A        X             2000     0 young left  low     0.0251  
 3 A        X             2000     0 young right high    0.000173
 4 A        X             2000     0 young right low     0.0648  
 5 A        X             2000     1 young left  high    0.0144  
 6 A        X             2000     1 young left  low     0.0164  
 7 A        X             2000     1 young right high    0.00336 
 8 A        X             2000     1 young right low     0.0355  
 9 A        X             2000     0 old   left  high    0.0304  
10 A        X             2000     0 old   left  low     0.0152
# ... with 118 more rows
```

I also have a data set, `Sample_DT`, as follows, which I want to [post-stratify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458098/correcting-dfs-when-using-sample-weights-with-lm) :

```
# A tibble: 158 x 6
      ID  year   Sex Age   Party Educ 
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1     1  2000     0 young left  high 
 2     2  2000     0 young left  low  
 3     3  2000     0 young right high 
 4     4  2000     0 young right low  
 5     5  2000     1 young left  high 
 6     6  2000     1 young left  low  
 7     7  2000     1 young right high 
 8     8  2000     1 young right low  
 9     1  2000     0 young left  high 
10     2  2000     0 young left  low  
# ... with 148 more rows
```

I want to create weights `wt` for each observation in the sample `Sample_DT`, based on `Population_percentages`. I figured that I should probably make the observation type with the most of occurrences (so highest percentage) have a weight of 1,

```
setDT(Population_percentages)[Percentage==max(Percentage), wt:= 1, by=c("Sex", "Age", "Party", "Educ","Province","Municipality", "year")]
```

and then calculate the other weights as follows:

```
setDT(Population_percentages)[Percentage!=max(Percentage), wt:= Percentage/max(Percentage)]
```

Subsequently merge with `Sample_DT`:

```
Sample_DT <- merge(Sample_DT, Population_percentages, all.x=TRUE, by=c("Sex", "Age", "Party", "Educ", "year"))

    Sex Age Party Educ year  ID Province Municipality Percentage    wt
1     0 old  left high 2000  41        A            Y     0.0169 0.235
2     0 old  left high 2000  41        A            X     0.0304 0.424
3     0 old  left high 2000  41        B            Y     0.0050 0.069
4     0 old  left high 2000  41        B            X     0.0573 0.798
5     0 old  left high 2000   9        A            Y     0.0169 0.235
```

Although this works, most of my sample weights are now lower than one. Because the absolute value of the weights matter, this reduces the significance of my estimates. But what would be a better strategy? If I make the lowest percentage one, my actual data will have ridiculous weights based on 1 observation and my significance will go through the roof. How should I deal with this?

## DATA

```
Population_percentages <- structure(list(Province = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B"), Municipality = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001), Sex = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), Age = c("young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old"), Party = c("left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right"), Educ = c("high", 
"low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", 
"high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
"low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", 
"high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
"low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", 
"high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
"low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", 
"high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
"low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", 
"high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
"low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", 
"high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
"low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", 
"high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
"low"), Percentage = c(0.00363305043470396, 0.0250648779857123, 
0.000173151256557699, 0.0648325996993254, 0.0144234728952913, 
0.0164319120632441, 0.00336426603304481, 0.0355229308678628, 
0.0304073691800687, 0.0151593449245738, 0.0367750850534511, 0.0158611757688454, 
0.0555368786996184, 0.0559842023706629, 0.0490588562283309, 0.0635027913886656, 
0.0362115476043335, 0.0564975688637761, 0.0544429190701162, 0.00366631981685772, 
0.0111387959134018, 0.0219135953292025, 0.00452171737546282, 
0.0572966054462462, 0.00978814372993392, 0.0366385326825001, 
0.0139308498890084, 0.0460551284332651, 0.0569828035677866, 0.0294668455717712, 
0.0188545169804561, 0.0568621448759225, 0.0406501036414465, 0.046384576972819, 
0.00502572608515079, 0.00258571887533766, 0.0198782819681412, 
0.0677119221201095, 0.020316969163509, 0.00293353901961675, 0.0169007465061072, 
0.0287028750197558, 0.0627493501010525, 0.0237612879430512, 0.0265630343683475, 
0.0526618049086282, 0.0473150000975084, 0.038575849920634, 0.00961605546340105, 
0.0393036298783691, 0.0297774347797188, 0.0285128013085276, 0.0249138112854196, 
0.0711612382030308, 0.00999362670159916, 0.0461318482289381, 
0.047898652249671, 0.0574548765901683, 0.00128538384143241, 0.0128885895969826, 
0.067526868182575, 0.0208874344258877, 0.0258466996853474, 0.00408426286771614, 
0.061420168994366, 0.0514901664570377, 0.0126223198575411, 0.0340834746947315, 
0.00417126034113316, 0.00876847650357606, 0.0305755498740512, 
0.0672308956367269, 0.0572656703601767, 0.0382888395116111, 0.0397128274016325, 
0.00263117723858853, 0.00790102034564815, 0.0139533255312594, 
0.0322697903259223, 0.00459290095244018, 0.0602307759806505, 
0.0485975274917308, 0.00147067491410715, 0.0421040555282206, 
0.00312463955780354, 0.0297944887719477, 0.0296687821091263, 
0.0213133813046203, 0.0180664051940893, 0.0570876462468417, 0.0336673240101317, 
0.0672213228629774, 0.0619089655598876, 0.0224256444857631, 0.0271987490750993, 
0.00914175288056017, 0.0141958701438663, 0.0527225913217579, 
0.00444058846326489, 0.0582124474424687, 0.018632067569775, 0.000950770222611701, 
0.0539343844220348, 0.0115772861837572, 0.00496519954573127, 
0.0449174118441341, 0.0194045279381461, 0.0376634104429328, 0.0423672466863044, 
0.0218128268380021, 0.042229017425358, 0.0406442048382822, 0.0545732302082367, 
0.0613447090607414, 0.0418169990373361, 0.00255507041810906, 
0.0183601419547765, 0.0717952815593631, 0.00281878518625843, 
0.0117100700469727, 0.0696509278941457, 0.0255333701034149, 0.0141095119237817, 
0.0326036470059355, 0.0749792978444943, 0.0205412871769699, 0.00428634278720498, 
0.0246514764638313)), row.names = c(NA, -128L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))



Sample_DT <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 
63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 
79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 
95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 
109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 
122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 17, 19, 21, 23, 17, 19, 21, 
119, 120, 123, 124, 127, 128, 128), year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001), Sex = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), Age = c("young", 
"young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", "young", 
"young", "young", "young", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old"), 
    Party = c("left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
    "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", 
    "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", 
    "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", 
    "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
    "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", 
    "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", 
    "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", 
    "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
    "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", 
    "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", 
    "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", 
    "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
    "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", 
    "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", 
    "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", 
    "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", 
    "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", 
    "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", 
    "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "left", "right", 
    "right", "left", "left", "right", "right", "left", "right", 
    "left", "right", "left", "right", "left", "right", "right", 
    "right", "right", "right", "right", "right"), Educ = c("high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high", 
    "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "low", 
    "high", "low", "high", "low", "low")), row.names = c(NA, 
-158L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

## "Proof" absolute value of weights matter

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(uid=1:200,
                      bp=sample(x=c(100:200),size=200,replace=TRUE),
                      age=sample(x=c(30:65),size=200,replace=TRUE),
                      weight=sample(c(1:10),size=200,replace=TRUE),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

set.seed(100)
df.double_weights <- data.frame(uid=1:200,
                      bp=sample(x=c(100:200),size=200,replace=TRUE),
                      age=sample(x=c(30:65),size=200,replace=TRUE),
                      weight=2*df$weight,
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


df.lm.aov <- anova(df.lm)
df.lm.aov$Df[length(df.lm.aov$Df)] <- 
        sum(df.lm$weights)-   
        sum(df.lm.aov$Df[-length(df.lm.aov$Df)]  ) -1
df.lm.aov$`Mean Sq` <- df.lm.aov$`Sum Sq`/df.lm.aov$Df
df.lm.aov$`F value`[1] <- df.lm.aov$`Mean Sq`[1]/
                                        df.lm.aov$`Mean Sq`[2]
df.lm.aov$`Pr(>F)`[1] <- pf(df.lm.aov$`F value`[1], 1, 
                                      df.lm.aov$Df, lower.tail=FALSE)[2]

df.double_weights.lm.aov <- anova(df.double_weights.lm)
df.double_weights.lm.aov$Df[length(df.double_weights.lm.aov$Df)] <- 
        sum(df.double_weights.lm$weights)-   
        sum(df.double_weights.lm.aov$Df[-length(df.double_weights.lm.aov$Df)]  ) -1
df.double_weights.lm.aov$`Mean Sq` <- df.double_weights.lm.aov$`Sum Sq`/df.double_weights.lm.aov$Df
df.double_weights.lm.aov$`F value`[1] <- df.double_weights.lm.aov$`Mean Sq`[1]/
                                        df.double_weights.lm.aov$`Mean Sq`[2]
df.double_weights.lm.aov$`Pr(>F)`[1] <- pf(df.double_weights.lm.aov$`F value`[1], 1, 
                                      df.double_weights.lm.aov$Df, lower.tail=FALSE)[2]

df.lm.aov

# Analysis of Variance Table

# Response: bp
#             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
# age          1   8741  8740.5  10.628 0.001146 **
# Residuals 1176 967146   822.4     

df.double_weights.lm.aov

# Analysis of Variance Table

# Response: bp
#             Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
# age          1   17481 17481.0  21.274 4.194e-06 ***
# Residuals 2354 1934293   821.7
```